# ajax send data based on checkbox value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to send ajax requests with checkbox values (on each click/check). I have three lists with checkboxes, each list filters the data returend from php (with mysql AND condition):

```
$('body').on('click', '.click, :checkbox, .pag_link', function() {

    var self = this;

    // radio buttons
    if ($('#res_prop').is(':checked')) {
        var use = $('#res_prop').val();
    }
    else if ($('#com_prop').is(':checked')) {
        var use = $('#com_prop').val();
    }
    else {
        $('p.error').show();
        die();
    }
    //checkboxes from each list have the same class, is this ok?
    if ($(self).is(':checkbox')) {
        $(self).on('change', function() {
            if ($(self).prop('class') == 'filter1' || $('.filter1').is(':checked')) {
                if ($('.filter1').is(':checked'))
                    var type = $(self).val(); // maybe should be an array
                else var type = null;
            } else var type = null;
            if ($(self).prop('class') == 'filter2' || $('.filter2').is(':checked')) {
                if ($('.filter2').is(':checked'))
                    var status = $(self).val(); // maybe should be an array
                else var status = null;
            } else var status = null;
            if ($(self).prop('class') == 'filter3' || $('.filter3').is(':checked')) {
                if ($('.filter3').is(':checked'))
                    var bhk = $(self).val(); // maybe should be an array
                else var bhk = null;
            } else var bhk = null;
        });
    }
    else {
        var type = status = bhk = null;
    }

    if ($(self).is('.pag_link')) {
        if ($(self).text() == '«')
            var page = (parseInt($('.active').text()) - 1);
        else if ($(self).text() == '»')
            var page = (parseInt($('.active').text()) + 1);
        else
            var page = parseInt($(self).text());
    }
    else {
        var page = 1;
    }

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/search',
        data: {
            'do': getUrlParameter('do'),
            'use': use,
            'type': type,
            'status': status,
            'bhk': bhk,
            'city': $('select[name="city"]').val(),
            'zone': $('select[name="zone"]').val(),
            'page': page
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        if ($( '#search' ).is(':visible'))
            $( '#search' ).hide();

        if ($(self).is(':checkbox')) {
        alert('should work');
            var new_content = $(data).find( '#scroll-to-list' );
            $( '#scroll-to-list' ).replaceWith( new_content );
        }
        else {
            var new_content = $(data).find( '#search-filters, #scroll-to-list' );
            $( '#results' ).html( new_content );
            $( 'html, body' ).animate({
                scrollTop: $( '#scroll-to-list' ).offset().top
            }, 1000);
        }

    });
});
```

I'm looking on each click/check to do the ajax request and print the new results (relying on server is performance-wise?). If checked, the variable gets the value and is sent, if unchecked the variable gets null. The search.php script handles the mysql Select query (with ifs adding the AND conditions to the query).

I just have 1 example in the db but the checkboxes script is not working (or the mysql select query is not including the and condition, i think the problem is in the jquery, the php script is fine).

```
$use            = isset( $_POST['use'] ) ? (int) $_POST['use'] : '';        // int AJAX
$filter_type    = isset( $_POST['type'] ) ? (int) $_POST['type'] : '';      // int AJAX
$filter_status  = isset( $_POST['status'] ) ? (int) $_POST['status'] : '';  // int AJAX
$filter_bhk     = isset( $_POST['bhk'] ) ? (int) $_POST['bhk'] : '';        // int AJAX
$filter_city    = isset( $_POST['city'] ) ? (int) $_POST['city'] : 0;       // int AJAX
$filter_zone    = isset( $_POST['zone'] ) ? (int) $_POST['zone'] : 0;       // int AJAX
$page_number    = isset( $_POST['page'] ) ? (int) $_POST['page'] : '';      // int AJAX

if ($filter_type != NULL || $filter_type != '') {
    $filter_type = 'AND t2.type = ' . $filter_type;
} else $filter_type = NULL;
if ($filter_status != NULL || $filter_status != '') {
    $filter_status = 'AND t2.status = ' . $filter_status;
} else $filter_status = NULL;
if ($filter_bhk != NULL || $filter_bhk != '') {
    $filter_bhk  = 'AND t2.bhk = ' . $filter_bhk;
} else $filter_bhk = NULL;

if ($filter_city > 0) {
    $filter_city = 'AND t2.city = ' . $filter_city;
    $filter_zone = NULL;

    if ($filter_zone > 0) {
        $filter_zone = 'AND t2.zone = ' . $filter_zone;
    }
} else $filter_city = $filter_zone = NULL;

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare(' SELECT t1.id, t2.*
                               FROM ' . $table . ' t1 // not from get/post
                               INNER JOIN property t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
                               WHERE t2.use = ?
                               ' . $filter_type
                                 . $filter_status
                                 . $filter_bhk
                                 . $filter_city
                                 . $filter_zone . '
                               LIMIT ?, ?')) {
    $stmt->bind_param('iii', $use, $start, $limit);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found this JQuery method [.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)... and it changed my life :)

```
$('body').on('click', '.click, :checkbox, .pag_link', function() {

    var self = this;

    if (!$(':radio').is(':checked')) {
        $('p.error').show();
        die();
    }

    var data = $('input, select').serializeArray(),
        mode = getUrlParameter('do'),
        page = 1;

    if ($(self).is('.pag_link')) {
        if ($(self).text() == '«')
            page = (parseInt($('.active').text()) - 1);
        else if ($(self).text() == '»')
            page = (parseInt($('.active').text()) + 1);
        else
            page = parseInt($(self).text());
    }

    data.push({ name : 'do',   value : mode});
    data.push({ name : 'page', value : page});

    alert($.param(data));
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/search',
        data: $.param(data)
    }).done(function (data) {
        if ($( '#search' ).is(':visible'))
            $( '#search' ).hide();

        if ($(self).is(':checkbox')) {
            var new_content = $(data).find( '#scroll-to-list' );
            $( '#scroll-to-list' ).replaceWith( new_content );
        }
        else {
            var new_content = $(data).find( '#search-filters, #scroll-to-list' );
            $( '#results' ).html( new_content );
            $( 'html, body' ).animate({
                scrollTop: $( '#scroll-to-list' ).offset().top
            }, 1000);
        }

    });
});
```

Hope it helps someone.